# Auto login in CakePHP 2.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using the registration form with several steps. After a new user registered with all the steps need to login to the dashboard page, I am getting the login credentials in the second step of registration and need to do the login functionality in step 5.  I am using Auth component for the authentication. I need solution especially for version 2.0
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is providing the login credentials in $this->request->data and call Auth->login().
That should automatically log this user in.

Comment: yes i tried in the same way but the error is Indirect modification of overloaded element of Cake Request has no effect. i cant over ride the request

Comment: yes you can. you probably wrongly addressed $controller->data instead of $controller->request->data (as I explained in my answer).